# Customize "Post to Facebook" copy below Add a comment

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, user-interface, interface

I have a client that is asking for a like with a "Post to Facebook". The down side is that they want the Like to point to the Facebook URL facebook.com/CLIENTSPAGE URL.  Is there a way to change the ICON and Title and description that is below the Add a comment box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you point a like button at a page on Facebook, the page's information is pulled.
If you point it at a page on your own server, you can use the Open Graph meta tags to set the metadata (title, description, picture, etc)

You need to choose one of those options, you can't change what information Facebook detects on the facebook page via your like button plugin

Comment: That's what I thought thanks, I'll just hide the icon title and description via css, do you know how the Huffington post adds "You like The Huffington Post. Unlike/Like" above the comments box?

Comment: Probably with a Like Box plugin